# Including extra data and fetching it when uploading a file using html form

Tags: php, iframe, file-upload

I'm quite new to php and I've been struggling for a time now with uploading through a form and an iframe(To imitate ajax) while also including more data than just the file itself(In my case, a string representing a date).
I tried searching for similar examples but could only find examples where they uploaded only the file which is already working correctly.

The form is similar to this(using bootstrap):

```
<form id="upload_pic_form" class="form-horizontal" action="upload_picture.php" 
  target="upload_target" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="form_content_wrapper">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Display from</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-append date" id="dpFrom" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                <input id="picFrom" class="span2" size="16" type="text" readonly>
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Display until</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-append date" id="dpTo" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                <input id="picTo" class="span2" size="16" type="text" readonly>
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Image</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input id="filename" type="text" class="input disabled" name="filename" readonly>
            <label class="btn" for="pic_file_input">Choose image...</label>
            <input id="pic_file_input" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" style="display: none;"/>        
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So now in upload_picture.php, I can get the file and all it's info by using $_FILES.
But how can I get the value of input "picFrom"?
I've tried using $_POST['picFrom'] but it gave me nothing.
Maybe I'm missing something super easy or being stupid, but please bear with me.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);` and see what you get.

Comment: Change `<input id="picFrom" class="span2" size="16" type="text" readonly> ` to `<input name="picFrom" id="picFrom" class="span2" size="16" type="text" readonly>`, then use `$picFrom = $_POST['picFrom'];` as your variable. Give that a try and let me know.

Comment: I noticed that all your `<input` have no `name` assigned to them. If you had `<input name="giveitaname"` to them, you will then be able to use them as POST variables in your PHP, such as `$giveitaname = $_POST['giveitaname'];`.

Comment: Yes, I was missing the name. I thought it used the id's to get the data. Thank you aswell.

Comment: @Grodslukarn You're welcome. Has it solved your problem?

Comment: Yes indeed, I am now able to correctly pass the data. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Grodslukarn Very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First be sure to close the form tag.
Then try adding `name='picFrom'` to the inputs(this is missing for each input element)
`$_POST` uses the `name` not the `id`.

Comment: I was under the impression that it used the id's. Now I know better and the code works flawlessly by using $_POST['picFrom'] and $_POST['picTo']. Thank you!